# Как оформлять такие предложения?

Tags: синтаксис, двоеточие, бсп

Сформулирую вопрос на конкретном примере. Есть текст, где идет развернутое пояснение слов «День был чудесный». Предполагается обширное описание состояния природы, состоящие из многих предложений. Если я ставлю после слова *чудесный* двоеточие и тем самым начинаю бессоюзное сложное предложение, значит ли это, что я лишаюсь возможности разделять части, содержащие описание природы, точками, а могу использовать лишь точки с запятой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно же, *внутри одного* предложения точки не используются (за исключением многоточия, оформления прямой речи или цитат) — как только Вы ставите первую точку, предложение заканчивается, и начинается другое.
Придется использовать точки с запятой. Или перестраивать предложение.

Приведу "свой пример".
Предложение из "Трех толстяков" Ю. Олеши (используется как [цитата](https://socratify.net/quotes/tri-tolstiaka-iurii-olesha/111077) или в упражнениях по расстановке знаков препинания):

> День был чудесный: солнце только то и делало, что сияло; трава была такой зеленой, что во рту даже появлялось ощущение сладости; летали одуванчики, свистели птицы; легкий ветерок развевался, как бальное воздушное платье.

На самом же деле [оригинальное предложение](http://books.rusf.ru/unzip/add-on/xussr_mr/oleshy01.htm?1/15) выглядит так (с изменениями, без двоеточия):

> На этот раз день был чудесный; солнце только то и делало, что сияло; трава была такой зеленой, что во рту даже появлялось ощущение  сладости; летали одуванчики, свистели птицы, легкий ветерок развевался, как воздушное бальное платье.

Вы — автор, и только от вашего воображения и уровня грамотности зависит, как скомпонуются отдельные предложения в единое целое, задуманное вами.

Вот отрывок из ["Войны и мира"](https://ilibrary.ru/text/11/p.269/index.html) Л. Н. Толстого:

> День был ясный, солнечный после дождя, и воздух был необыкновенно чист. Дым не стлался низом, как в тот день, когда Пьера вывели из гауптвахты Зубовского вала; дым поднимался столбами в чистом воздухе.

Предложения при желании можно объединить в одно или, наоборот, разделить на три, но автор выбрал именно такую пунктуацию.

[Бессоюзное сложное предложение](https://www.anews.com/p/121939235-bessoyuznoe-slozhnoe-predlozhenie-primery-znaki-prepinaniya-v-bessoyuznom-predlozhenii/)
[Запятая и точка с запятой в бессоюзном сложном предложении](https://old-rozental.online/punctum_uk.php?pid=337)